# Creating a multi leveled listview application

Tags: android, listview, hierarchy

So here is the code.  Its pretty self explanatory.  The only problem I am having is retaining the value for int level.  Its lost every time.  I need the value to be retained and it will work.  This is a snapshot.  It should be extensible to as many levels deep and as many items per level.

XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
package com.example.kjkjsdkjdsjkdfs;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
String categoryselected = "main";
public int level = 0;

@SuppressWarnings("null")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] array;
    Intent received = getIntent();
    // Setup as main ListView
    if (received == null || !received.hasExtra("array")) {
        array = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };
    }

    // Setup as sub ListView
    else {
        array = received.getStringArrayExtra("array");

    }
    if(received != null || !received.hasExtra("level")) {
        level = received.getIntExtra("level", 0);
    }
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    level = level + 1;
    Intent starting = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    switch (level) {
    case 1:
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            starting.putExtra("array", new String[] { "1a", "1b", "1c" });
            starting.putExtra("level", level);
            break;
        case 1:
            starting.putExtra("array", new String[] { "2a", "2b", "2c" });
            starting.putExtra("level", level);
            break;
        case 2:
            starting.putExtra("array", new String[] { "3a", "3b", "3c" });
            starting.putExtra("level", level);
            break;
        }

        break;

    case 2:
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            starting.putExtra("array", new String[] { "1aa", "1ab" });
            starting.putExtra("level", level);
            break;

        }

        break;
    case 3:
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            starting.putExtra("array", new String[] { "1aaa", "1aab" });
            starting.putExtra("level", level);
            break;
        }
        break;
    }

    startActivity(starting);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you talking about to retain the value of this variable `public int level = 0` ?

Comment: yes, so when i repeat the click event it seems to always be one when it should be incrementally going up by one.  Seems never to get to the second (case 2) for level.

Answer (score 2):

**Update** your code like this :

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListItems extends ListActivity {
    String categoryselected = "main";
    public int level = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] array;
        Intent received = getIntent();
        // Setup as main ListView
        if (received == null || !received.hasExtra("array")) {
            array = new String[] { "1", "2", "3" };
        }

        // Setup as sub ListView
        else {
            array = received.getStringArrayExtra("array");

        }
        if(received != null || !received.hasExtra("level")) {
            level = received.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        level = level + 1;
        Intent starting = new Intent(ListItems.this, ListItems.class);
        switch (level) {
        case 1:
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                starting.putExtra("array", new String[] { "1a", "1b", "1c" });
                starting.putExtra("level", level);
                break;
            case 1:
                starting.putExtra("array", new String[] { "2a", "2b", "2c" });
                starting.putExtra("level", level);
                break;
            case 2:
                starting.putExtra("array", new String[] { "3a", "3b", "3c" });
                starting.putExtra("level", level);
                break;
            }

            break;

        case 2:
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                starting.putExtra("array", new String[] { "1aa", "1ab" });
                starting.putExtra("level", level);
                break;

            }

            break;
        case 3:
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                starting.putExtra("array", new String[] { "1aaa", "1aab" });
                starting.putExtra("level", level);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }

        startActivity(starting);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: if i test it out it using the first position in the listview(aka case 0) it goes directly from 1 to 1aaa instead of 1a.

Comment: i would just copy everything but these comment sections seem to have a limited amount of characters.

Comment: It doesnt for me.  It goes directly to case 3 of int level on the first click.  Litterally copied and pasted your code over mine and that was the result.  Any ideas?

Comment: ok the  }
        if(received != null || !received.hasExtra("level")) {
            level = received.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        } is being highlighted under the word recieved stating that that value can only be null at that location.

Comment: I copied 100% of the updated code and changed Listitems to MainActivity(three times).  Since there was a warning, as mentioned above, I suppressed it so that it would run and the result is the same. Ali I greatly appreciate your help.  I am using the latest version of ADT.  Can someone else verify that this works.

Comment: Anyone? Please give a brother a hand.

Comment: As the above code is working according to your description, so in this case no one can help you further more.

Comment: The point is that it doesn't work for me.  I do not doubt it works for you.  Can you troubleshoot with me?

Comment: Ok, then what is the problem you currently facing with this code ?

Comment: Code has been updated.  I had to add a supressWarnings to get it to run but it does not work as upon loading the activity and selecting the one of the first set of listview items it goes to the third tier instead of the second one.  It just isnt working properly.  Thanks again!